# Minipage inside long table

Tags: tables, minipage

I have large table going more than one page .

```
\documentclass[useAMS]{biom}
\begin{table*}
 \centering
 \def\~{\hphantom{0}}
 \begin{minipage}{140mm}
  \caption{Models and Explicit Estimates}
\label{t:tableone}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}
  \Hline 
   \multicolumn{2}{l}{1) My title (MCAR model)}\\
\Hline
Some Text & Some Text  \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

When I try to keep going in this table; after one page I do not see any table extending into second page. I want to continue the same table in next page.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why have  a minipage inside the table? (a table is already effectively a minipage)

Comment: Or, since you use `tabular*`, change  to the `tabularx` environment, and load the `ltablex` package to allow tabularx environments to break across pages (no use to load tabularx nor longtable in that case: ltablex does it for you).

Comment: because this what the journal's format is.. Is it possible to control the numbering of table in this environment ? When I type another table, I get the heading Table 2. Instead of Table 2 I want Table 1 continued.. Is this possible ?

Comment: Do not use two table environments (they may float to non-consecutive pages) use a `longtable` environment from the package of eh same name.

Comment: It is not working even if I use long table... I am still not able to get rid of automatic numbering table 2 ...